# load csv via ruby into hash then selecting element from hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash, load

I am learning ruby today and got stuck with extracting single element from the hash.

### login1.csv

```
role,uName,passwd
adm,admin1,a1
mgr,manager,m
user,user1,u1
adm,admin2,a2
```

### ruby code

```
def csvIntoHash
  # load csv Into hash
  $table = []
  File.open("logIn1.csv") do|f|
    columns = f.readline.chomp.split(',')
    until f.eof?
      row = f.readline.chomp.split(',')
      row = columns.zip(row).flatten #build hash from array
      $table << Hash[*row]
    end
  end
end
#
#main
csvIntoHash
#pulls all hash elements when role=mgr
puts $table.select {|rEntry| rEntry["role"]=="mgr"}
```

How do i extract only the uName when role=mgr then assign it to a variable?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`select()` returns an Array, so look at the first (only, in your case?) entry, which is a Hash as you constructed it:

```
mgrh = $table.select {|rEntry| rEntry["role"]=="mgr"}
mgr_role = mgrh.first["uName"] # => "manager"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [CSV library in Core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

From the format of your CSV on here, if what you really want it to get the `uName` of the manager, I have the following solution.

```
manager = ""
CSV.read("file.csv").each_with_index do |arr, index|
  role_column = arr.index("role") if index == 0
  if arr[role_column.to_i] == "mgr"
    manager = arr[role_column.to_i + 1]
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**
Obviously this assums there is only one manager in the CSV sheet. You can modify the code to assign an array of managers if so required.